# Using \renewcommand to change the References name is not working

Tags: bibliographies, report

I am creating a dissertation style document in LaTeX and am required to use the universities layout which is a premade code I have saved and added in to my premable. At the moment the title for the bibliography reads 'Reference' but I want it to read 'Bibliography'. I have seen other pages on here that tell you to add in this line

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
```

which I have done but it has not changed anything for me. Below is the code I have used, have I done anything wrong? Is there a command I need to add into the bibliography itself?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}


    \bibitem{derbyshire} J. Derbyshire.{\em Unknown Quantity}, Atlantic, London (2007).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I add `\begin{document}` to your code, then it works fine. The renewcommand works to replace the name of the bibliography, which is not really necessary in the example, as "Bibliography" is already the default value. Can you make a small example, that shows your problem?

Comment: Sorry that's a mistake on my behalf, I do have \begin{document} I'll change it now. It doesn't work because I'm using a package for a layout. So how can I force it to change?

Comment: A good start would be to tell us the name of the package that prevents it from working. Maybe something with `babel`? We cannot read minds :)

Comment: It is a package my university has created which allows you to fill in details and produces pages like the declaration automatically. It is called bbkproject but I dont think this will help you as it is just the name for the file that my uni has created for me to insert into the project

Comment: http://www.bbk.ac.uk/ems/faculty/hart/latex-resources this one?

Comment: Yes that's the one

Comment: Gotta love 'em templates.

Comment: @Johannes_B Templates are great. Whenever I'm in doubt if the latex code in my own document is to messy, randomly opening a template will most probably convince me that my own document is fantastic and does not need to be cleaned up :)

Comment: That comment made my day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{bbkproject}

\makeatletter
\gdef\@bibname{Bla}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{thebibliography}{99}


    \bibitem{derbyshire} J. Derbyshire.{\em Unknown Quantity}, Atlantic, London (2007).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay this works, thank you! Would you mind just explaining to me what \makeatletter does and \makeatother? And do you know why my way wasn't working?

Comment: @harry55 `\makeatletter` makes @ a letter, which is necessary if you want to use @ in your preamble. As to why your way was not working: this is simply because the package you are using seems to be quite a mess and the name was defined there like this ...

Comment: @harry55 see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: `\makeatletter
\gdef\@bibname{Bla}
\makeatother`
did not work with the documentclass `article`