# Keeping the abstract on one page when using a template

Tags: margins, page-breaking

I am writing a dissertation style document and am using a template made by my uni, [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358812/using-renewcommand-to-change-the-references-name-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment884349_358812) may be of use. My abstract has to read *exactly* as it is so deleting words/rewording isn't an option. As you can see by the image I've provided it goes onto another page by three words. How can I change this? Is there a way I can change the page dimensions slightly for this page only and not the rest of the template?

The template can be found [here](http://bbk.ac.uk/ems/faculty/hart/latex-resources), it is called bbkproject.

[image: Abstract]

Comment: you can probably put `\looseness=-1` just before the paragraph,  or add `\endlargethispage{\baselineskip}` or (normally if not in this case simply re-word it a bit).

Comment: Neither of those options work for me as it is a template where the title page creates the abstract (see link provided for template) and it cannot be reworded as mentioned above.

Comment: I assume (?) you can't abbreviate "Chapter" to "Ch. "

Comment: No I must create a duplicate of the text I am given so shortening words, deleting words or rewording is not possible.

Comment: I'd look at the blank lines around lines 315--329 of the template, as they only appear in the abstract, or see if `\frenchspacing` wins you enough.  But @DavidCarlisle's suggestion of `\looseness` should work -- you should be able to put it in the argument passed to the template

Comment: you make it hard for anyone to debug since you have not provided an example here just an image but I fail to see wht you can not put `\looseness=-1` in wherever you are adding the text. whether it's triggered by `\maketitle` or not you must add the text somewhere.

Comment: Can you please make a MWE? As I said for your questions yesterday, we are no mind readers - this is still true today.